# Is there any way that you can receive radio signals on your raspberry pi?

Tags: radio

Since the Raspberry Pi can do frequency modulation by using the PiFM to turn your raspberry pi into a transmitter, is there anyway that you can receive VHF on your Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. No you can't do it without some special hardware (VHF TX/RX module/usb dongle in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Buy a cheap RTL USB dongle and then use RTL-SDR http://sdr.osmocom.org/trac/wiki/rtl-sdr